# Worst case complexity analysis of a Binary Tree function "leaves"

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, binary-tree

I wonder if my complexity analysis (T worst case for n elements/nodes) is correct for the following function leaves in Haskell (Note: wurzel = root; C = constant factor)

```
--abstract data type for bin trees

data Bintree el = Empty
                  | Node {left :: Bintree el, root :: el, right :: Bintree el} 
                    deriving Show

--extract all leaves of a given Bintree (output: list)

leaves :: Bintree el -> [el]
leaves Empty = []
leaves (Node Empty root Empty) = [root]
leaves (Node left root right) = leaves left ++ leaves right
```

[image: rendered complexity analysis]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are many mistakes. Here are a few of the more glaring ones:

- When you write `T(n/2)+T(n/2)+T(n/4)+T(n/4)+...`, you seem to be assuming that half of the nodes are in the left branch and half are in the right. That's not always true -- some trees are balanced, but some certainly are not.
- Even if the tree is balanced, there are not only 2 subtrees of size n/4 -- there are 4. Similarly there are 8 subtrees of size n/8, not 2.
- The correct expression to describe "dividing `n` by 2 `i` times" is `n/(2^i)`, not `n/(i^2)`. Additionally, the above comment about balancing notwithstanding, you would want to keep dividing until you reached just one leaf, so the correct base case of the ellipsis is `T(n/n)`, not either one of `T(n/(2^n))` or `T(n/(n^2))`.
- If you repeatedly divide by two, and add the results, as in `n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ...`, forever, you get `2*n`, not `log_2(n)`.
- Anyway, that doesn't apply, because you are not adding multiples of `n`. `T(n) + T(n/2) + T(n/4) + T(n/8) + T(n/16) + ...` is not necessarily related in any special way to `T(2*n)` (nor to `T(log_2(n))`). For example, imagine if `f(n) = 1`. Then the sum `f(1) + f(1/2) + f(1/4) + f(1/8) + f(1/16) + ... = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...` diverges, even though `f(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...) = f(2) = 1`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your fast answer. I thought that Binary Trees need to have 2 childs.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Yes, internal nodes in binary trees have two children. Do you believe part of my answer disagrees with that? If so, which part?

Comment: @Doesbaddel An internal node in a binary tree has *at most* 2 children. A *full* binary tree is a special case in which every internal node has exactly 2 children.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.